# concat person names according to specific movie and their job

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to concat person names according to their job if he is an editor I want to them to be concat in one string for this specific movie however duo to I use `LEFT JOIN` I get this [query result](https://ibb.co/hHgC2Lh). Is there a way how I can get only one row for a movie? I don't need to have 5 star wars movie rows.

```
SELECT
movie.movie_id,
movie.title, 
movie.budget,
movie.release_date,
movie.runtime,
CASE movie_crew.job
 WHEN 'Director' THEN string_agg(person.person_name,',')
END AS Director
CASE movie_crew.job
 WHEN 'Editor' THEN string_agg(person.person_name,',')
END AS Editor
FROM movie
LEFT JOIN movie_crew ON movie.movie_id=movie_crew.movie_id
LEFT JOIN person ON movie_crew.person_id=person.person_id
WHERE movie_crew.job in ('Director','Editor')
GROUP BY movie.movie_id,movie_crew.job
limit 100;
```

[DB schema](https://ibb.co/VSBtwr2)

Comment: If you want one row per movie, you'd need to only `group by movie.movie_id`.

Comment: This error I get when  GROUP BY movie.movie_id only `ERROR:  column "movie_crew.job" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 7: CASE movie_crew.job`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `group by` has to be only by `movie_id`, so we need to avoid referencing the non-aggregated `movie_crew.job`. We can do this by replacing the `case movie_crew.job` with a [`filter` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) on `string_agg`.

We can even get fancy and order the lists.

```
SELECT
movie.movie_id,
movie.title, 
movie.budget,
movie.release_date,
movie.runtime,
string_agg(person.person_name,',' order by p.person_name)
  filter (where movie_crew.job = 'Director' order by person.person_name)
  as Directors,
string_agg(person.person_name,',' order by p.person_name)
  filter (where movie_crew.job = 'Editor' order by person.person_name)
  as Editors
FROM movie
LEFT JOIN movie_crew ON movie.movie_id=movie_crew.movie_id
LEFT JOIN person ON movie_crew.person_id=person.person_id
GROUP BY movie.movie_id
limit 100;
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5ccf9d68d5af1c692257ef080800377f).

Filter clauses are an optional SQL:2003 feature. Only PostgreSQL and SQLite support them. It can be emulated by putting the case inside the `string_agg` call.

```
string_agg(case when mc.job = 'Director' then p.person_name end, ', ' order by p.person_name)
    as directors
```

Comment: O my god it did really worked, thank you so much!. I did find smth like this on a different topic but didn't get SQL code so many thanks for the explanation.